# How do I use an apply function in R to find the maximum of a variable for subgroups

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset, apply

```
 salary <- data.frame(name=c("Kay","Dave","Jon","Jenny","Jim","Eve","Ed"),
 salary=c(60000, 100000, 50000, 80000, 30000, 40000, 20000),
 gender=factor(c("F","M","M","F","M","F","M")))
```

I am able to filter a female data frame with

```
femaleFiltered <- salary[ which(salary$gender=='F'), ]
```

and I am trying to use

```
getMaxSal1 <- function(x) {
    x[which.max(x$salary),]
}

apply(femaleFiltered,2,getMaxSal1)
```

but get error "Error in x$salary: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(femaleFiltered, salary == max(salary))
#   name salary gender
#4 Jenny  80000      F
```

---

Or as per OP's requirement about a possible use of *`apply`

```
femaleFiltered[unlist(lapply(names(femaleFiltered), 
       function(nm) which.max(femaleFiltered[nm]$salary))),]
#   name salary gender
#4 Jenny  80000      F
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .... I need to do it using any of the apply functions in R only.. I was able to get the answer using female[which.max(female$salary),]... however I need to use apply function only..

Comment: @RohitGoswami what is `female` in the data.  your object defined is `salary`

Comment: femaleFiltered is the filtered data frame with gender==F

Comment: @RohitGoswami do you want just `subset`.  Updated the post

Comment: yes that is the output i want but using any apply functions in R

Comment: @RohitGoswami That is a strange requirement because `apply` is not really needed here

Comment: true.. as i mentioned i already get the answer using femaleFiltered[which.max(femaleFiltered$salary),] but can we do it using apply or it really is not possible?

Comment: @RohitGoswami anything can be done, but this is a very roundabout way of solving the problem

Comment: agree.. but that's the requirement :D

Comment: @RohitGoswami do you need `unlist(lapply(names(femaleFiltered), function(nm) getMaxSal1(femaleFiltered[nm])))`

Comment: nice we get the salary.. is it possible to get the name and gender along with the salary?

Comment: @RohitGoswami when you are looping over `apply`, with `2`, it is a vector of columns and thus you are having error.  If you need both, then probably you need to get the index out instead of `x[which.max(x$salary),]`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
aggregate(salary$salary, by=list(salary$gender), FUN = max)
```

oh just read about needing to do an apply function.

Make a list of two data frames, one for males, one for females.

Then use lapply()  with FUN = max.

```
lapply(list(femaleFiltered$salary, maleFiltered$salary), max)
```